# Смена структуры java/android проекта в структуру Gradle

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

Собственно есть структура проекта

- AndroidManifest.xml
- assets
- ibs
- res
- src
- всякие файлики

При импорте проекта в тот же Android Studio, она сама добавляет gradle и переделывает структуру в вид:

- app

  - libs
  - src

    - main

      - assets
      - java
      - res
      - AndriodManifest.xml
    - build.gradle
- всяке файлики

Как с помощью gradle или какого иного способа, изменить структуру проекта не используя тот же импорт в студию?

Есть ли какая то консольная команда у gradle, что бы при добавлении его в проект через терминал, можно было бы перестроить проект? Или что то, что делало бы это.

Comment: Gradle сам по себе ничего об этом не знает и ничего такого не умеет. Это все `com.android.tools.build:gradle` плагин делает, копайте в эту сторону.

Comment: Вот: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html

Comment: Там есть информация о том как заменить директории исходников для java.

Comment: А вообще, чем Вам не нравится общепринятый стандарт?